# Sendmessage from NT Service to remote desktop session

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

How can i send a sendmessage & postmessage from nt service to an application which launched in a remote desktop session? currently i temporarily solved this problem via udp communications between applications.

Comment: If you don't want to use TCP/IP, named pipes are easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot send messages across session boundaries. So you need an IPC solution like TCP/IP, sockets, named pipes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make a program that does a sendmessage/postmessage:

program sendit;
uses converters;
begin
  exitcode:=sendmessage(covert1(paramstr(1)),convert2( .... etc
end.

Then run it in the right session with CreateProcessAsUser. You can wait ([WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for the program to exit, at which point the sendmessage completed. It's very slow though :).

You can also go with pipes/IPC, but you can still launch the "server" using CreateProcessAsUser. Use Jwa for getting tokens and such.

And use better names than I just did :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the WTSSendMessage api: Displays a message box on the client desktop of a specified Remote Desktop Services session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa383842(v=vs.85).aspx

Or use the Jedi Windows Security library which wraps this in nice delphi like objects